# Google Maps API - Return only the duration in minutes or seconds as a whole number

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have created an App to streamline patient triage during mass casualty events.

The backbone of the data it operates on is based in a Google Spreadsheet.

One of the things I want to add to the app is to provide transit times using live data from the google maps api from a set location ie. the airport and each of the twelve level 1 and 2 trauma centers in the region.
The idea being that it would show "true" travel time to each hospital taking into account live traffic data.
This could be used to prioritize more critical patients to hospitals with less transit time to them during peak traffic hours.

I know how to return the directions from point A to point B...

=importdata("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Dallas+Fort+Worth+International+Airport&destination=Baylor+Medical+Center+Grapevine&key=AIzaSyBvLbKphCUuY9RNfn73hU3Tse0KbM7gQTA")

Bu this returns way too much data I don't need, and I really just want the transit time value in minutes as a whole number or in seconds as a whole number.

I could add a cell that says =A25 for example, that is the cell that the duration shows up in, but then I get the whole value "Text" Duration : "9 min" or something like that which isn't useful to me either.

That way I can use it in a column next to the hospital and conditional format the cells green-yellow-red based on the median time between each location.
This would provide a quick reference for the Medical Operations Officer to see which hospitals are the fastest to get to.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the directions API, but instead you want the Distance Matrix API, that will give you distance and duration only.

Learn more about the distance Matrix API here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Your request translated to DM would look like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Dallas+Fort+Worth+International+Airport&destinations=Baylor+Medical+Center+Grapevine&mode=driving

the response looks like this:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "1650 W College St, Grapevine, TX 76051, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [
      "DFW International Airport, 2400 Aviation Dr, DFW Airport, TX 75261, USA"
   ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "12.4 km",
                  "value" : 12442
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "9 mins",
                  "value" : 568
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: I originally used the distance matrix API, but that only gives "histrorical" travel time for that route. I was told the Directions API pull takes into account the current live traffic data from google maps, but I'm not 100% sure. I created a work around using the "value" result and then the formula   =value(right(A2652,len(A2652)-8))/60   which seems to be working. It's not elegant but neither am I lol.

Comment: Only Premium Plan projects get duration_in_traffic, otherwise you simply get duration

Comment: What does "value" refers to with the duration, is it the time in seconds?

Comment: Yes indeed, value in duration is seconds as stated in the documentation:
"duration: The length of time it takes to travel this route, expressed in seconds (the value field) and as text."
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview#elements